# Can we start Our app when the phone starts on Android API 30?

Tags: java, android

i wrote these in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

```
<receiver android:name=".StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and this is my java class:

```
public class StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Your Device Rebooted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(activityIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote these codes many time but still not working. I think it's not working because i'am using API 30. Can you please help me:

Answer (score 0):

You can start a Service or BroadcastReceiver.  You can't start an Activity from the background anymore except under very specific circumstances.